# The following SQL statement used to work, but now I am getting an unknown column error for a column that I know exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I did not write this code initially, but it did work at one time.  Unfortunately it is no longer working.  My research suggests it is a mismatch in SQL types, but I am not well versed enough in SQL to fix the error.  Hopefully someone here can direct me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`users`.`card_id` ) AS `card_id2`
, `users` .`firstname` AS `First Name`
, `users`.`lastname` AS `Last Name`
, `users`.`card_id` AS `Card ID`
, `users`.`address1` AS `Address`
, `users`.`address2` AS `Address2`
, `users`.`city` AS `City`
, `users`.`state` AS `State`
, `users`.`zip` AS `Zip`
, `users`.`email` AS `Email`
, `users`.`phone_area`
, `users`.`phone_exchange`
, `users`.`phone_number`
, `trans`.`trans_dt` AS `Last Trans Date`
, `trans`.`credit_balance` AS `Credit Balance`
, `trans`.`balance` AS `Gift Balance`
, `users`.`gender` AS `Gender`
, `users`.`birthdate` AS `Birthday (Age)`
, `users`.`register_dt` AS `Registration Date`
, `merchants`.`company`
, `merchants`.`merchantkey`FROM `trans`
, `users`
, (SELECT `card_id`, max( `trans_id` ) AS `trans_dt` 
   FROM `trans` 
   WHERE `trans`.`trans_type` >0 GROUP BY `card_id`
) AS `trans_max` 
LEFT JOIN `merchants` ON `merchants`.`merchantkey`=`trans`.`merchantkey` 
WHERE trans.card_id = users.card_id 
AND trans.card_id = trans_max.card_id 
AND trans.trans_id = trans_max.trans_dt 
ORDER BY users.lastname, users.firstname;



Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'trans.merchantkey' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this for SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Which one is it?

Comment: Can you add the actual error stack trace?

Comment: If this is your actual code, do you realize that there's a space between `'users'` and `.'firstname'`?  Maybe okay for your SQL dialect, but don't know.

Comment: I have removed the [tag:sql-server] tag. It must be MySQL because of the back-ticks.

Comment: `WHERE trans.card_id = users.card_id ` ::trans is not visible from the outer query.

Comment: *I get an error about an unknown column, but I"m not going to tell you which one it is or show you my database schema. Can you wade through this mess and try to figure it out?* The error message tells you **exactly** which column it can't figure out; why are you being so rude as to ask us for help without providing that information? You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem** - the very least you can do is give us the information you have **right on the screen in front of you**.

Comment: You have deleted `FROM users`

Comment: Sorry Ken, I copied and pasted the error initially, not sure why or how it was removed from the question.  I have added it in now.

Comment: Thank you Bill, it is MySQL.

Comment: STLDevleoper, yes this is the actual code, I fixed that typo but it did not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests you don't actually have a `merchantkey` field in your `trans` table. I think you do have that field, and the error is caused by mixing join styles. You've got the deprecated ANSI-89 style (`FROM tablea, tableb WHERE a.key = b.key`) as well as the proper ANSI-92 style (`FROM tablea JOIN tableb ON a.key = b.key`). Both work independently, but mixing them creates a precedence issue, as the ANSI-92 style joins are evaluated before the ANSI-89 style joins. This precedence issue creates the error because you reference a field in your `LEFT JOIN` that hasn't been evaluated yet. Switching to all proper ANSI-92 style joins is good practice, and should fix your error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (users.card_id ) AS card_id2
, users .firstname AS `First Name`
, users.lastname AS `Last Name`
, users.card_id AS `Card ID`
, users.address1 AS Address
, users.address2 AS Address2
, users.city AS City
, users.state AS State
, users.zip AS Zip
, users.email AS Email
, users.phone_area
, users.phone_exchange
, users.phone_number
, trans.trans_dt AS `Last Trans Date`
, trans.credit_balance AS `Credit Balance`
, trans.balance AS `Gift Balance`
, users.gender AS Gender
, users.birthdate AS `Birthday (Age)`
, users.register_dt AS `Registration Date`
, merchants.company
, merchants.merchantkey
FROM trans 
JOIN users 
  ON    trans.card_id = users.card_id 
JOIN (SELECT card_id
            , max( trans_id ) AS trans_dt
      FROM trans
      WHERE trans.trans_type > 0 
      GROUP BY card_id
    ) AS trans_max
  ON    trans.card_id = trans_max.card_id 
   AND  trans.trans_id = trans_max.trans_dt  
LEFT JOIN merchants 
  ON     merchants.merchantkey = trans.merchantkey  
ORDER BY users.lastname, users.firstname;
```

MySql Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

It looks like this precedence issue was not always in place, but that it may have been introduced in MySQL 5.7, so if the query previously worked, it could be that it was previously running on an earlier version.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly after I added some quotes to the multi-word AS field names.  I had seen another article telling me that the issue was this ANSI mismatch, but I did not fully understand it, or have the expertise to fix it.  Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't notice those fields when I went on a back-tick removing spree, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and paste your query above.  The `FROM` clause is in the wrong spot.  There is no space between `merchants.merchantkey` and `FROM trans`.  Why are there some more `SELECT` clause after `FROM` clause, then followed by `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
, `merchants`.`company`
, `merchants`.`merchantkey`FROM `trans`
, `users`
, (SELECT `card_id`, max( `trans_id` ) AS `trans_dt` 
   FROM `trans` 
   WHERE `trans`.`trans_type` >0 GROUP BY `card_id`
) AS `trans_max` 
LEFT JOIN `merchants` ON `merchants`.`merchantkey`=`trans`.`merchantkey`
...
```

I am thinking your `FROM` is out of place.  Try to move the `FROM` clause before the `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`users`.`card_id` ) AS `card_id2`
    , `users` .`firstname` AS `First Name`
    , `users`.`lastname` AS `Last Name`
    , `users`.`card_id` AS `Card ID`
    , `users`.`address1` AS `Address`
    , `users`.`address2` AS `Address2`
    , `users`.`city` AS `City`
    , `users`.`state` AS `State`
    , `users`.`zip` AS `Zip`
    , `users`.`email` AS `Email`
    , `users`.`phone_area`
    , `users`.`phone_exchange`
    , `users`.`phone_number`
    , `trans`.`trans_dt` AS `Last Trans Date`
    , `trans`.`credit_balance` AS `Credit Balance`
    , `trans`.`balance` AS `Gift Balance`
    , `users`.`gender` AS `Gender`
    , `users`.`birthdate` AS `Birthday (Age)`
    , `users`.`register_dt` AS `Registration Date`
    , `merchants`.`company`
    , `merchants`.`merchantkey
    , `users`
    , (
        SELECT `card_id`, max( `trans_id` ) AS `trans_dt` 
        FROM `trans` 
        WHERE `trans`.`trans_type` >0 GROUP BY `card_id`
    ) AS `trans_max` 
FROM `trans`
LEFT JOIN `merchants` ON `merchants`.`merchantkey`=`trans`.`merchantkey`
WHERE trans.card_id = users.card_id 
    AND trans.card_id = trans_max.card_id 
    AND trans.trans_id = trans_max.trans_dt 
ORDER BY users.lastname, users.firstname;
```

Comment: `users` is another table, it's a comma delimited list of tables/subqueries using the deprecated join syntax, then a proper join tacked on for good measure.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for the suggestions.  I tried your code as written and got a generic SQL Syntax error @ the SELECT statement that's in the parentheses.  I then adjusted your code to move the orphaned 'users' immediately before the aforementioned SELECT error, and put it down in the FROM statement, but the Syntax error remained.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I believe the SELECT statement within the parentheses is creating a temporary table from with I am selecting something which is why it comes after the FROM statement.  As I said I didn't write this code and it is far beyond the level of SQL I am comfortable with.

Comment: by the way,  space between merchants.merchantkey and FROM trans made no difference to the initial code.